# Ready-To-Go .NET Project Templates

Tags: .net, project-template

Can anyone point me towards .NET 3.5 or 4.0 project templates for desktop development (WPF and/or WinForms) that have today's most commonly used libraries/frameworks already setup?  The template would include things like:

- Logging (e.g. log4net)
- Templating (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146013/template-engine-for-net-environment)
- ORM layer (e.g. NHibernate or EF)
- Options form with use patterns shown (and maybe one or two example options)
- Installation project
- Testing framework (e.g. NUnit)
- Command line parsing
- Bootstrapping class using command line parser, etc...
- An MVC framework.
- Maybe an IoC framework.

Really, the more the better.  I've looked through Visual Studio's online templates and found nothing impressive.  Also, searching Google hasn't turned up much other than many old articles that at most just include logging or one of the above items.

I'm looking for a complete package template.

Comment: Why to have template with such mixed things inside? What is the problem with adding things yourself, exactly what you need? For example, with [NuGet](http://nuget.org/)

Comment: NuGet looks really good - I have never heard of it.  I ask for a template because not only do I need the libraries, but usually when you add a library there are a number of small wrapper classes and things and configurations that you have to add around the library.  I would like to find a project template that has already taken care of that and more.  I don't see how this could be a bad thing at all!

Comment: It is exactly what NuGet is for.

Comment: I've posted it as answer with some additional links to documentation and conference video about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [NuGet](http://nuget.org/). [Here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingNuPackPackageManagementForNETAnotherPieceOfTheWebStack.aspx) and [here](http://docs.nuget.org/), and [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM09) is some video about NuGet too.

It allows you to add needed packages without much pain of configuring them and referencing many things etc.

Comment: Ivan, I installed and have tried NuGet. You missed a big part of my question, which is that I'm looking for a project template that takes care of some of the hum-drum wrapping around common packages.  E.g. log4net you have to add some configuration to your application.  I want a template that: 1) has the log4net library installed and 2) has the sample configuration in the .config file.  Or, if I install the EF Code First package, I want there to be a sample DbContext class and so on.  Thanks for showing me NuGet, but I can't accept your answer as it only addresses part of my question.  Thanks.

Comment: @Chad: NuGet can manage your config files and transitive references and much more. The very first link I gave you after official NuGet website is Scott Hanselman's blog post that describes how NuGet manages config needed for `elmah` package. And as for your question - I'm pretty sure that you won't find such template as there's almost no possibilities for a single application to use _everything_. Or at least everything you've mentioned.